# Verificar si un string está en base64 antes de codificarlo

Tags: java, android, base64

Tengo un código en una app de android que codifica y decodifica en `base 64` un `String` que se pasa como parametro. El problema es que hay veces en las que no el `String` no está en `base 64`, como puedo checkear que el `String` esté en `base 64` antes de decodificarlo?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public static String decodificarBase64(String cadena) {
    String cadenaDecodificada = cadena;
    try {
        if (cadena != null && !cadena.trim().equals("")) {
            cadenaDecodificada = new String(Base64.decode(cadena, Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(e.getMessage(), "|" + cadena);
    }
    return cadenaDecodificada;
}
```

Comment: Lo más normal sería decodificar y ver si hay una excepción; si eres extra precavido hacer que el String original tenga un formato determinado (p.ej que empiece siempre por "12345") y comprobar que el resultado siga teniendo el formato. ¿Por qué no quieres hacerlo así?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente expresión regular para saber si una cadena está codificada en Base64 o no

```
^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$
```

Los caracteres introducidos en Base64 son `[A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and + /]`. Si el resto de la longitud es menor de 4 la cadena se pasa con el caracter `=`

`^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*` Significa que la cadena comienza con 0 o más grupos de Base64.

`([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$` Significa que la cadena finaliza de una de las siguientes tres formas: `[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}`, `[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=` o `[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==.`

Puedes encontrar la referencia de origen en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571501/how-to-check-whether-the-string-is-base64-encoded-or-not

Comment: ¿El número de caracteres en la cadena es siempre múltiplo de 4?